# Why is import pandas giving me an error message?

Tags: pandas

Hi I have installed pandas into my virtual environment in VS Code. I can import other modules that came when pip installed pandas(numpy) but it gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aidan/VS_Studios/Graphing Data/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

When I try and import pandas into my main.py file. This is my virtual environment:

[image]

I have wheels installed and have python running on 3.11.8 and everything is local.
Please help thank you!

I have tried unistalling pandas and checking to see if both my interpreter pip and python are all on the same version, they are. IDK what else I need to do.

Comment: Have you activated your python environment correctly?  From VSCode docs: [select-and-activate-an-environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment)

Comment: I activated the environment using the command pallet, both the environment and the interpreter are on 3.11.1. As well, I am able to import other modules from the local environment just not pandas